# How to detect X container crash from Y container

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I have a specific requirement where I have a POD with 4 containers. Yes, 4 :-)
We are moving step by step towards a more containerized model. Please excuse me.
Now there is a requirement for container W need to know whether container X,Y,Z are up or down at real time. Is there a built-in feature available in K8s? Or should we use our own HTTP/TCP liveness checks?

Comment: I'd try making the network connection you'd normally make; if you get a "connection refused" error then the other container isn't available right now (might not have started yet, or failed, or ...).  An easy way to recover is to just crash, and Kubernetes will restart you after some delay.

Answer (score 1):

Your own HTTP/TCP liveness checks are workable because containers in the same pod can contact each other via `localhost`. Example if container x is listening to port 80 with a healthcheck path `/healthz`, your container w can do `curl -sI http://localhost/healthz -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}"` to check for 200 OK response.